# Eliminar en un árbol AVL genérico

Tags: java

Estoy haciendo una implementación del código para crear un árbol AVL genérico y una función que me gustaría agregar en este árbol es poder eliminar un nodo, pero no logro entender donde debo poner las funciones de rotaciones que ya tengo para poder eliminar no se si alguien me pueda ayudar adjunto los códigos de mi programa. Ya en la implementación ya tengo las rotaciones que deben hacer para que el árbol este equilibrado y se que primero debo buscar el nodo a borrar y de ahí borrarlo hacer el cambio con sus hojas si es que tiene y de ahí revisar el factor de equilibrio pero no logro entender donde debo hacer esto y de ahí cuando debo hacer la rotación

```
public class Nodo <T>
{
   private T elemento;
   private Nodo izq;
   private Nodo der;

   private int factorEquilibrio;

   // Constructores
   public Nodo( T elemento) {
       this (elemento, null, null );
   }
   public Nodo( T elemento, Nodo izq, Nodo der ){
       this.elemento = elemento;
       this.izq = izq;
       this.der = der;
       factorEquilibrio = 0;
   }
   public int getFactorEquilibrio()
   {
       return factorEquilibrio;
   }

   public T getElemento()
   {
       return elemento;
   }

   public Nodo getIzq()
   {
       return izq;
   }

   public Nodo getDer()
   {
       return der;
   }

   public void setIzq(Nodo izq)
   {
       this.izq = izq;
   }

   public void setDer(Nodo der)
   {
       this.der = der;
   }

   public void setFactorEquilibrio(int mFE)
   {
       this.factorEquilibrio = mFE;
   }
}//Fin Clase Nodo
```

```
package Negocio;

public class Arbol
{
    private Nodo raiz;

    public Arbol()
    {
        this.raiz=null;
    }
    public Nodo getRaiz()
    {
        return raiz;
    }

    public void insertar( Comparable elemento ) {
        raiz = insertar ( raiz, elemento );
    }

    private Nodo insertar (Nodo arbol,Comparable elemento) {
        if (arbol == null) {
            arbol = new Nodo(elemento, null, null);
        } else if (elemento.compareTo(arbol.getElemento()) < 0) {
            arbol.setIzq(insertar(arbol.getIzq(), elemento));
            if (factorEquilibrio(arbol.getDer())-factorEquilibrio(arbol.getIzq()) == -2 ){
                if (elemento.compareTo(arbol.getIzq().getElemento()) < 0)
                    arbol = RotacionSimpleDer(arbol);
                else
                    arbol = RotacionDobleIzq_Der(arbol);
            }
        } else if (elemento.compareTo(arbol.getElemento()) > 0) {
            arbol.setDer(insertar(arbol.getDer(), elemento));
            if (factorEquilibrio(arbol.getDer())-factorEquilibrio(arbol.getIzq()) == 2){
                if (elemento.compareTo(arbol.getDer().getElemento()) > 0)
                    arbol = RotacionSimpleIzq(arbol);
                else
                    arbol = RotacionDobleDer_Izq(arbol);
            }
        } else {
            ;
        }
        arbol.setFactorEquilibrio(
                mFE(factorEquilibrio(arbol.getIzq()),
                        factorEquilibrio(arbol.getDer())));
        return arbol;
    }

    private static Nodo RotacionSimpleIzq(Nodo arbol) {
        Nodo subArbol = arbol.getDer();
        arbol.setDer(subArbol.getIzq());
        subArbol.setIzq(arbol);
        arbol.setFactorEquilibrio( mFE(factorEquilibrio(arbol.getIzq()),
                factorEquilibrio(arbol.getDer())));
        subArbol.setFactorEquilibrio( mFE(factorEquilibrio(subArbol.getDer()),
                arbol.getFactorEquilibrio()));
        return subArbol;
    }

    private static Nodo RotacionSimpleDer(Nodo arbol) {
        Nodo subArbol = arbol.getIzq();
        arbol.setIzq(subArbol.getDer());
        subArbol.setDer(arbol);
        arbol.setFactorEquilibrio( mFE(factorEquilibrio(arbol.getIzq()),
                factorEquilibrio(arbol.getDer())));
        subArbol.setFactorEquilibrio( mFE(factorEquilibrio(subArbol.getIzq()),
                arbol.getFactorEquilibrio()));
        return subArbol;
    }

    private static Nodo RotacionDobleIzq_Der(Nodo arbol){
        arbol.setIzq(RotacionSimpleIzq(arbol.getIzq()));
        return RotacionSimpleDer( arbol );
    }

    private static Nodo RotacionDobleDer_Izq(Nodo subArbol){
        subArbol.setDer(RotacionSimpleDer(subArbol.getDer()));
        return RotacionSimpleIzq(subArbol);
    }

    public static int factorEquilibrio(Nodo arbol){
        if (arbol==null)
            return 0;
        else
            return (arbol.getFactorEquilibrio()+1);
    }

    private static int mFE( int alturaIzquierdo, int alturaDerecho ) {
        if (alturaIzquierdo > alturaDerecho)
            return alturaIzquierdo;
        else
            return alturaDerecho;
    }

    public void imprimirArbolNiveles(Nodo arbol, int nivel) {
        if (arbol != null) {
            imprimirArbolNiveles(arbol.getIzq(), nivel + 1);
            System.out.println (" " + nivel + " " + arbol.getElemento());
            imprimirArbolNiveles(arbol.getDer(), nivel + 1);
        }
    }


}//Fin Clase Arbol
```

```
package Presentacion;

import Negocio.Arbol;
import Negocio.Nodo;

public class PruebaABB_AVL
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Arbol ObjetoArbol = new Arbol();
        ObjetoArbol.insertar(30);
        ObjetoArbol.insertar(20);
        ObjetoArbol.insertar(40);
        ObjetoArbol.insertar(15);
        ObjetoArbol.insertar(22);
        ObjetoArbol.insertar(25);
        ObjetoArbol.insertar(27);
        ObjetoArbol.insertar(21);
        ObjetoArbol.imprimirArbolNiveles(ObjetoArbol.getRaiz(), 0);
    }
}
```